# Is it okay to say, "I am increasingly older."

Tags: adverbs, progressive-aspect, redundancy

Is it okay to say, "I am increasingly older." when I mean to say "I am growing more and more older."

Comment: I can't formulate this to a full answer, but I'd say there is some slight connotation that the rate of getting older is increasing; whether for humour or just as a dour interpretation of how it feels to be getting older, idk.

Answer (score 3):

No, the sentence is not grammatical as it stands - or at least, it does not convey the meaning you intend. Semantically, it seems confusing, at least.

> I am older.

This means that you are comparing your age to someone or something else.

> I am older than my brother.
>   My brother is 34, I am older.

The construction of an attributive with the copulative *am* means that you are describing a *state*, not a process. (*)

Adding an adverb (increasingly) to it does not change that. The adjective may give the idea that you describe the process (getting older), but the verb *am* describes that it is a specific momentary state (*am* older). You can mix those up, but the meaning will not be clear.

The verb *get* is indeed a better choice:

> I am getting increasingly older.

This sentence makes perfect sense. **But** it is, as rogermue mentioned in his comment, a so-called *platitude*. Nobody ages "decreasingly", so it seems a bit meaningless to add that your getting older is happening in an "increasing" way.

---

(*) Yes, if you use the correct attributive, you can use *am* when describing a process; you basically describe that your *state* is "being in the process":

> I am ageing.

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically valid and makes logical sense, though it seems kind of weird to me idiomatically. I'd probably say, "I'm getting older."

Answer (score -1):

Yes, *"I am increasingly older?"* is fine to say. No one on earth is getting increasingly younger. All increasingly older means is that every day/hour/minute/second/millisecond that goes by you are getting older.

Comment: I would not say it is fine. It's a platitude.

Comment: "No one on earth is getting increasingly younger."  Not true.  My wife is getting increasingly younger.  And you can tell her I told you.